# Get letter grade using eval()

Tags: python

I understand that using eval is extremely dangerous as it can execute deadly commands as an input by the user.

I'm trying to write a code to get a letter grade from a number between 0 to 1. I was trying to write it in the most elegant way. Is this safe?

```
try:
    score = float(raw_input('Enter score: '))
except Exception as ex:
    print 'Score must be a number!'
    quit()

if score > 1: 
    print 'Score must be less than 1'
    quit()

grades = {
    'A': str(score) + '>= 0.9',
    'B': str(score) + '>= 0.8',
    'C': str(score) + '>= 0.7',
    'D': str(score) + '>= 0.6',
    'F': str(score) + '< 0.6',
}

for key in sorted(grades):
    if eval(grades[key]): 
        print key
        quit()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Striving to make your code data-directed is a laudable goal.  However, as you suspected, `eval()` is not a good way to do it, and it is almost always the wrong approach.

I don't believe that your program is exploitable, since the only scores that would be fed to `eval()` would be valid floating-point values.  However, it is possible to make your program throw a `NameError` if you enter `-inf` as the score.

Rather than `eval()`, you would be better off representing the conditions as lambdas.  There isn't much of an advantage of using a dict, since the entries have to be considered in a specific order.  An ordinary list would be better.  An [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) could work too.  Furthermore, the table is a constant, so it should be named using the `ALL_CAPS` convention.

```
GRADES = [
    ('A', lambda score: score >= 0.9),
    ('B', lambda score: score >= 0.8),
    ('C', lambda score: score >= 0.7),
    ('D', lambda score: score >= 0.6),
    ('F', lambda score: True),
]
```

You shouldn't need to litter your code with `quit()` calls if you structure the code properly.

<s>You don't have to write `except Exception` if you want to catch everything.</s>. You don't have to write `except Exception as ex` if you don't care about examining the exception.

```
try:
    score = float(raw_input('Enter score: '))
except Exception:
    print 'Score must be a number!'
else:
    if score > 1:
        print 'Score must be less than 1'
    else:
        for grade, condition in GRADES:
            if condition(score):
                print grade
                break
```

Comment: Thank you! That's a very clever solution and very good advice, I don't know much about lambda. Just started python :). I'll look into that further. That looks very elegant!

Comment: Why use lambdas instead of just `GRADES = { A: 0.9, B: 0.8, C: 0.7, D: 0.6, F: 0 }` and test `if score >= condition` in the loop?

Comment: @WChargin I was trying to stick to the intent of the original code. The threshold approach works well too, and deserves to be posted as an answer.

Comment: You should never, never **ever** have an empty `except:`, because that catches everything, including any `KeyboardInterrupt`s, `SystemExit`s and any other gremlins. `Exception` is as low as you should go.

Answer (score 4):

You're right to suspect that using `eval` stinks: it really does.

You can define the values of `grades` as tuples of functions and a parameter:

```
def greater_than_or_equal(score, x):
    return score >= x

def less_than(score, x):
    return score < x

grades = {
    'A': (greater_than_or_equal, 0.9),
    'B': (greater_than_or_equal, 0.8),
    'C': (greater_than_or_equal, 0.7),
    'D': (greater_than_or_equal, 0.6),
    'F': (less_than, 0.6),
}
```

Now you can write a `get_grade` function that returns the correct grade using the evaluator and a parameter:

```
def get_grade(score):
    for key in sorted(grades):
        evaluator, param = grades[key]
        if evaluator(score, param):
            return key
```

I converted the code that just prints the key and quits to a function,
so that you can verify the correct behavior using assertions:

```
assert 'F' == get_grade(0.1)
assert 'F' == get_grade(0.5)
assert 'D' == get_grade(0.6)
assert 'D' == get_grade(0.61)
assert 'C' == get_grade(0.7)
assert 'B' == get_grade(0.8)
assert 'A' == get_grade(0.9)
assert 'A' == get_grade(0.91)
assert 'A' == get_grade(1)
```

Actually, using a dictionary for `grades` doesn't make a lot of sense.
It could be just a list of tuples in the correct order so that you can even skip the sorting step:

```
grade_evaluators = (
    (greater_than_or_equal, 0.9, 'A'),
    (greater_than_or_equal, 0.8, 'B'),
    (greater_than_or_equal, 0.7, 'C'),
    (greater_than_or_equal, 0.6, 'D'),
    (less_than, 0.6, 'F'),
)

def get_grade(score):
    for evaluator, param, grade in grade_evaluators:
        if evaluator(score, param):
            return grade
```

Comment: Thanks Janos! This is one of those things where I wished I could have marked two answers as answers. Your answer is also amazingly great.

Answer (score 3):

- You can use if-else-elif conditions here instead of a `dict` with `eval`.
- We can ask the user continuously for input until the they give us correct input by using a while loop and move the user-input part to a separate function. We can also specify the type of input we expect from user, whether `int` or `float`, default being `int`.
- Move the main code inside of a function as well, we use `main()` and call it from `if __name__ == '__main__'`.
- I am not sure you want to allow negative scores as well, if that's the case below case is easily modifiable.

**Code:**

```
import sys


def get_score(input_type=int):
      while True:
          try:
              score = input_type(raw_input('Enter score: '))
              return score
          except ValueError as e:
               print 'Invalid input, please try again.'


def main():

      score = get_score(float)

      if 0.9 <= score <= 1:
            print 'A'
      elif 0.8 <= score < 0.9:
            print 'B'
      elif 0.7 <= score < 0.8:
            print 'C'
      elif 0.6 <= score < 0.7:
            print 'D'
      elif 0 <= score < 0.6:
            print 'F'
      else:
            print 'Score {} is not between 1 and 0.'.format(score)


if __name__ == '__main__':
      main()
```

---

Note that when the number of options are huge then writing so many `if-elif`'s will make our huge and hard to read as well, in that case we can use the [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) module(considering the scores to be compared are sorted). Here I've used the function [`bisect_right`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect_right) from the bisect module, it returns the rigt-most index where a score can fit in a list of sorted scores.

```
from bisect import bisect_right


def main(values, options):

      score = get_score(float)
      min_score = values[0]
      max_score = values[-1]

      if score < min_score or score > max_score:
            print "Score {} is not between {} and {}".format(score, min_score, max_score)
      elif score == max_score:
            print options[-1]
      else:
            index = bisect_right(values, score)
            if values[index] == score:
                print options[index]
            else:
                print options[index-1]


if __name__ == '__main__':
      values = [0, 0.6, 0.7, .8, .9, 1]
      options = 'FDCBA'
      main(values, options)
```

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't call `quit`; it's intended only for use in the REPL. Instead, try returning gracefully from a `main` function.

You should not catch a raw `Exception` as this will hide real errors; try `ValueError` instead. There's no need to give it a name if you never use it either.

You should probably check both sides of `score`:

```
if not 0 <= score <= 1: 
    print('Score must be in the range [0, 1]')
    return
```

Grading should be factored out. I also expect it'd be simpler with `bisect`:

```
from bisect import bisect_right

GRADES           = 'F', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A'
GRADE_BOUNDARIES =      .6,  .7,  .8,  .9

def score_to_grade(score):
    index = bisect_right(GRADE_BOUNDARIES, score)
    return GRADES[index]
```

This all gives

```
from bisect import bisect_right

GRADES           = 'F', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A'
GRADE_BOUNDARIES =      .6,  .7,  .8,  .9

def score_to_grade(score):
    index = bisect_right(GRADE_BOUNDARIES, score)
    return GRADES[index]

def main():
    try:
        score = float(raw_input('Enter score: '))
    except ValueError:
        print('Score must be a number!')
        return

    if not 0 <= score <= 1: 
        print('Score must be in the range [0, 1]')
        return

    print(score_to_grade(score))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that one could use a simple string lookup and accomplish this in a single line:

```
def grade(value):
    return "FFFFFFDCBAA"[int(10*value)]
```

Range checking is done by the `[]` lookup, so an exception is thrown if the value is not in the half-open range [0,1.1).